# Display centered page header in a sub report which is placed in a multi column formatted section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

More than a full day gone and i still can't find a solution...

I am creating a report which will be used to print out an exam paper(Crystal Reports with VS 2010). All exams have more than one related unit and all units have their own questions.

So i have created a sub report with the units and questions and added to the main reports' Details section which formatted as multicolumn. I have generated the report which seems like below.

http://www.avekon.com/tmp/examprintscreen0.png

Everything is fine until now. But when i want to add the unit titles (which are in the subreport),they are displayed as headers of each column. I want to display the unit title as centered on the top of each page, like below.

http://www.avekon.com/tmp/examprintscreen.png

- Tried to add a header to main report and update it from subreport. NOT WORKED! Because the variables are not while the subreport is looping.
- Tried to format other sections as multi column. NOT POSSIBLE as i see.
- Tried to insert sub report into sub report. NOT POSSIBLE again.

and i have tried a lot of other logical and illogical ways but no success at the end. It should be easy but i can not find the right way. Please help, really important!

Comment: How is your subreport related to the main report? Is there a UnitID that you're using to select the data?

Comment: I am passing ExamID to subreport and subreport gets all units which are related to that exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the multi-column formatting from the main report and instead, format the sub-report as multi-column.

This should do the trick.

Comment: But sub report uses a group and group headers can not be formatted as multi column :s

Comment: which version of crystal are you using? in mine after enabling multiple columns in the section expert under detail... a new "layout" tab appears with an option "format groups with multiple columns"